# How can I Imagemagick lib in vc6.0?

Tags: c++, image-processing, imagemagick

...

How can I Imagemagick lib in vc6.0?
How can I Imagemagick lib in vc6.0?

Answer (score 1):

> MS vc6.0(it looks like a very old version)

It *is* a very old version, and it has the disease many MS products from this time have: It doesn't work well with standards (like the C++ standard here, or proper HTML/CSS/JS in IE6, or...). Because of this (and the age in general), many projects gave up to support it long ago.

Throw it away, ImageMagick won't work.

You don't need to buy something else: If you like VS, for all newer VS versions, there are free editions to download, else GCC/Clang are completely free.

Comment: As I know, one of the ImageMagicK can used in vc6.0

Comment: @nanana What do you mean with "one of the"? I know only one project named Imagemagick which makes a programming lib.

Comment: @nanana Sure, some old version will run on VS6. But same old version will not have all features of the newer ones, and instead some bugs which are fixed in newer versions.

Comment: I don't care new features and bugs. The important is which ImageMagicK working well in vc6.0. If you don't mind would you please let me know how to build and compile in vc6.0 more exactly? I can't find anywhere it's documents or tutorial like.

Comment: @nanana `I don't care ... bugs. The important is which ImageMagicK working well` "Bug" means that it won't work well. And if you insist on VS6, please do it alone. I won't help doing horrible things which are a pain for you and everyone else who gets this code.

Comment: But you told me ImageMagicK is working vc6.0 then just let me know if you know how to build and compile. What if I have meet the error then I'll go to turn vc2015.